# Удалить одинаковые элементы по одному элементу кортежа и меньшими по другому

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, group-by, tuple

Есть список кортежей, в котором, в каждом кортеже есть два целочисленные значения, возраст и количество.

Нужно удалить из списка одинаковые кортежи по возрасту, но оставить самые большие по количеству.

Вот сам список:

```py
out = [
    (36, 0), (37, 0), (27, 0), (31, 0), (30, 0), (18, 0), (29, 0), (34, 0),
    (32, 0), (23, 0), (27, 0), (20, 0), (25, 0), (40, 0), (29, 0), (19, 0), 
    (26, 0), (21, 0), (21, 1), (20, 1), (26, 1), (20, 1), (35, 1), (19, 1),
    (33, 1), (18, 1), (23, 1), (20, 1), (17, 1), (20, 1), (23, 1), (19, 1),
    (30, 1), (19, 1), (22, 1), (24, 1), (30, 1), (19, 1), (21, 1), (16, 1),
    (62, 1), (17, 1), (17, 2), (17, 3), (17, 4), (20, 4)
]
```

Например, вот кортежи: `(17, 1), (17, 2), (17, 3), (17, 4)`, из всех кортежей по значению возраста 17. Нужно оставить один со значением количества 4, а все нулевые количества тоже удалить.

Comment: вы бы хоть попробовали, вот так, не заморачиваясь, например, `dict(sorted(out))[17]` даст 4

Comment: То что вы новичёк в Python, все отнесутся с пониманием. Но в русском то вы не новичёк. Как это понять: _оставить один со значением количества 4, а все нулевые количества тоже удалить_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

отсортируйте список, по умолчанию будет сортироваться сначала по первому, а потом по второму членам кортежей. Теперь можно сделать словарь, в нем останутся максимальные значения, и преобразовать обратно в список

```
newList = list(dict(sorted(out)).items())
```

Comment: Элегантное решение!

Comment: Я только сути не понял. Мы добавляем в список, элементы словаря, но откуда мы берем словарь?

Comment: словарь сделается из списка кортежей. просто распечататйте результат каждого этапа, станет пончтнее

Comment: @splash58, спасибо большое! Очень помогли

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь [itertools.groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

res = [max(g, key=lambda x: x[1])
       for c,g in groupby(sorted([x for x in out if x[1] != 0]), lambda x: x[0])]
```

---

результат:

```
In [18]: res
Out[18]:
[(16, 1),
 (17, 4),
 (18, 1),
 (19, 1),
 (20, 4),
 (21, 1),
 (22, 1),
 (23, 1),
 (24, 1),
 (26, 1),
 (30, 1),
 (33, 1),
 (35, 1),
 (62, 1)]
```